# Javascript form submit issue occured

Tags: javascript

I am designing a website with multiple pages. I used an ajax call to load my data into a container. Every page works well and opens. I designed a signup form that opens using ajax call into container. Before it all pages works JavaScript codes using main.js file but when i open sign up page and gave an id to submit button and call an alert function on its click event. It is not showing any alert. I used a console function but the same think here and not appear any type of error or console message at this page.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please step first to [HELP center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), then read [How to Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and provide a [MCVE : Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If people around can easily read and understand what you mean, or what the problem is, they'll be more likely willing to help :)

Comment: Provide some code, pls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens, because you try to bind event on element, that has been created after your event listeners were declared. You have to trigger event using your document via any parent node element , or document, as element with highest hierarchy.

```
$(document).on('click', '#yourEl', function(){alert('clicked');})
```

Comment: thanx, it's working now... great help